# I am trying to have two columns in my block, however, the content overflow outside of the block. How do I solve it?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two columns in my block. The result of my code is I am having my bullet lists overflow outside of the block area. How do I adjust the problem?

Here is my code as a snippet:

```css
#education{
    padding:50px 15px 20px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #dcd9d9;
    text-align:center}
#education h2{color:#374054;margin-bottom:50px}
.education-block{
    max-width:700px;
    margin:0 auto 30px auto;
    padding:15px;
    border:1px solid #dcd9d9;
    text-align:left;
}
.education-block h3{
    font-weight:500;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    color:#374054
}
.education-block span{
    color:#74808a;
    float:right}
.education-block h4{
    color:#74808a;
    clear:both;
    font-weight:500;
    margin:0 0 15px 0}
.education-block p,.education-block ul{
    margin:0;
    color:#74808a;
    font-size:0.9em
}
.education-block ul{padding:0 0 0 15px}
```

```html
<div id="education">
        <h2 class="heading">Education</h2>
        <div class="education-block">
            <h3>A University</h3>
            <span class="education-date">Sep 2018 - Present</span>
            <h4>Master of Computer Science</h4>
            <p>
                The courses intened to take are:
            </p>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>A:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        B
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        C
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        D
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>E:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        F
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        G
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        H
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

In this case, BCD and FGH is not included inside the education-block. I am trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure exactly how do you want it to look, but because of theese clases i think you are using bootstrap and triying to get two cols whith the lists.

In that case you must wrap all in a div with class row and this in a div with class container or container-fluid, like this:

```
<div id="education">
        <h2 class="heading">Education</h2>
        <div class="education-block">
            <h3>A University</h3>
            <span class="education-date">Sep 2018 - Present</span>
            <h4>Master of Computer Science</h4>
            <p>
                The courses intened to take are:
            </p>

         <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

             <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>A:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        B
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        C
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        D
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div>

             <div class="col-xs-6">
                <p>E:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        F
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        G
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        H
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </div> 

           </div> <!-- Row -->              
         </div> <!-- Container-->

        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, all the boostrap element should be included inside the container and row div.